# Building a 4D matrix from 1D array duplicated

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

In python, Suppose I have a 1D array C (c dimensions), and I want to construct a 4D matrix of dimension a x b x c x d, such that the array is **duplicated** along all other axes.

I.e. no matter what the dimension 1, 2 and 4 indexes are, array[i][j][**k**][l] = C[**k**]

Is there any numpy function to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an array `ar`, you could use [`np.broadcast_to`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html), to get that higher dim array as a view (hence virtually zero runtime and no memory overhead), like so -

```
np.broadcast_to(ar[None,None,:,None],(a,b,len(ar),d))
```

Sample run -

```
In [115]: ar = np.random.rand(10)

In [116]: a,b,d = 3,4,5

In [117]: np.broadcast_to(ar[None,None,:,None],(a,b,len(ar),d)).shape
Out[117]: (3, 4, 10, 5)
```

If you need output with its own memory space, append with `.copy()`.

Leading newaxes(None) are optional. Hence, alternatively -

```
In [121]: np.broadcast_to(ar[:,None],(a,b,len(ar),d)).shape
Out[121]: (3, 4, 10, 5)
```